# How to get a first hash tags element in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

1. Now I'm writing a MongoDB query to get the first hashtag elements in a string. I had a document that has a file named test which format like `Alligator May Have Killed Man in Louisiana During #HURRICANE Ida Aftermath #GPWX` #HURRICANE should be the first element of the hashtag. Another text example is `#HurricaneIda Exposes Grid Weaknesses as #NewOrleans Goes Dark`. #HurricaneIda should be the first element(Since it appeared at the first).
2. I was wondering can I use $regx to get the first hashtag element in a text on MongoDB? I'm not familiar with regular expressions, so can someone give me some tips?

Answer (score 0):

if the string field was `data`
`{data:"Alligator May Have Killed Man in Louisiana During #HURRICANE Ida Aftermath #GPWX"}`

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
  {
    '$project': {
      'f': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': {
            '$split': [
              '$data', ' '
            ]
          }, 
          'as': 'z', 
          'cond': {
            '$regexMatch': {
              'input': '$$z', 
              'regex': '#.*'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'data': {
        '$first': '$f'
      }
    }
  }
]
)
```